# How to save a copy of the current data driven page to a new map file?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I need to copy the current data driven page to a new ArcMap Document using arcpy so that I can make sure the file name follows the naming schema that we have defined and the user cannot change. Is it possible to do this with arcpy?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using? Where are you hoping to run this code from?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 and everyone will be running the same.

Answer (score 2):

As you loop through each page in Python, you can do `mxd.saveACopy(path_out)` and it would save a map with the current page as active. I don't know why you would want to do this over just using the Data Driven Pages toolbar in ArcMap, though.

Comment: we want a copy of just the one page for people to edit and we can keep the original edit-free.

Comment: @user17350 I'm struggling to understand the use case too.  I suspect you may be wanting the output to be non-DDP-enabled with the index polygon feature Select-ed out to replace the data source of your index layer.  How are you planning to trigger this copy?

Comment: We decided to go with another route, but thanks.